# Pass true/false state from a child to the parent- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I would like to change a true/false state in a child component and pass it to a parent component, where the state is actually defined. Right now, this results only in an error.

Parent:

```
const PostTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  const [isSlider, setIsSlider] = useState(false);

  return (
        <Layout class="page">
          <main>
                <Views setIsSlider={isSlider} {...data} />
          </main>
        </Layout>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Child:

```
const Views = (data) => {
  return (
      <div
        key="views"
        className="post__gallery views"
      >
        {data.views.edges.map(({ node: view }) => (
          <divy
            onClick={() => setIsSlider(true)}
          >
            <GatsbyImage
              image={view.localFile.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData}
            />
            <div
              className="post__caption"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: view.caption,
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Right now, this puts out:

```
setIsSlider is not a function.
(In 'setIsSlider(true)', 'setIsSlider' is false)
```

Perhaps also relevant the console.log from React:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Comment: Best make a function in the parent to switch the value, then pass the fuction as a prop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing `isSlider` as a prop. You should be passing `setIsSlider`.

Note that state management in React is a complex topic and you probably want to do some research into how it is done in general. Directly passing a state setting callback works, but it doesn't scale well to complex applications.

Comment: Is the below components mix such too “complex” so that it won't work anymore?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing the **state variable** you have to pass the **state function** like this:

**Parent**

```
const PostTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  const [isSlider, setIsSlider] = useState(false);

  return (
        <Layout class="page">
          <main>
                <Views setIsSlider={setIsSlider} {...data} />
          </main>
        </Layout>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

**Child**

You've to use `data.<function_passed_via_props>` to access the `setIsSlider` function, like this:

```
const Views = (data) => {
  return (
      <div
        key="views"
        className="post__gallery views"
      >
        {data.views.edges.map(({ node: view }) => (
          <divy
            onClick={() => data.setIsSlider(true)}
          >
            <GatsbyImage
              image={view.localFile.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData}
            />
            <div
              className="post__caption"
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: view.caption,
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This has all been immensely helpful! But what about a situation like below?

Answer (score 1):

To Fix: Change `setIsSlider={isSlider}` into `setIsSlider={setIsSlider}`.

However, in case you need to manage more than a few states across components. I would suggest using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/). This can centralize your common-used states, you can access or update these states in any component using Redux.